# Deleting the top item of SQLite database causes the app to crash

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, sql-delete

I am using an SQLite database class that I found online. When I delete the top item and try to reload the database the app crashes because the database does not reasign IDs. This means that for two items with IDs 1 and 2, if I delete the first item the second maintains ID 2. So when the cursor tries to access the DB it calls the item with ID 1 (which does not exist anymore) and the app crashes. I'm not experienced with SQLite. I think what the problem is that the DB does not reasign IDs to its items after one is deleted.

The SQLite code I'm using

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UsersDB.db";
public static final String USER_TABLE_NAME = "Users";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_SURNAME = "surname";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_JOB_TITLE = "job_title";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_LEVEL = "level";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_ROLE = "role";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
private HashMap hp;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(
            "create table Users " +
                    "(id integer primary key, name text, surname  text, job_title  text, level  text, role  text, phone  text)"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users");
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertUSER (String name, String surname, String job_title, String level, String role, String phone) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("surname", surname);
    contentValues.put("job_title", job_title);
    contentValues.put("level", level);
    contentValues.put("role", role);
    contentValues.put("phone", phone);
    db.insert("Users", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from Users where id="+id+"", null );
    return res;
}

public int numberOfRows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, USER_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}

public boolean updateUSER (Integer id, String name, String surname, String job_title, String level, String role, String phone)  {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("surname", surname);
    contentValues.put("job_title", job_title);
    contentValues.put("level", level);
    contentValues.put("role", role);
    contentValues.put("phone", phone);
    db.update("Users", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}


public Integer deleteUSER (Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("Users",
            "id=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllUsers() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from Users", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(!res.isAfterLast()){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(USER_COLUMN_NAME)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
}
```

And I'm accesing the DB with this code

```
DBHelper userDB =new DBHelper(context);

    size=userDB.numberOfRows();
    Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(size),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(size>0){
        main_label.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        main_listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        data=new String[size][2];
        ids=new int[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            Cursor cursor;
            cursor=userDB.getData(i+1);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            data[i][0]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.USER_COLUMN_SURNAME));
            data[i][0]+=" "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.USER_COLUMN_NAME));
            data[i][0]+="\n"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.USER_COLUMN_JOB_TITLE));
            data[i][1]=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.USER_COLUMN_PHONE));
            ids[i]=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex((DBHelper.USER_COLUMN_ID)));
            if (!cursor.isClosed())  {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        customAdapter = new ListAdapterUsers(context,mActivity,data,ids,size);
        main_listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }else {
        main_label.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        main_listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

This line causes the crash

```
cursor=userDB.getData(i+1);
```

with the error

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

If I change the code to cursor=userDB.getData(i+2); then it works normally because there is an item with ID of 2

Is there something missing from my DB? I tried using db.exec("Vacuum"); after deleting but did not work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *I think what the problem is that the DB does not reasign IDs to its items after one is deleted* This is not a problem. This is normal. The column `id` is not a row number. It is a column just like the others. So your code must not rely on the value of the id of a row.

Comment: OK I see. I think I will store a row number and reassign it manually after the deletion. Thank you

Comment: The way you are accessing your database is wrong, you need a cursor to loop through your data